# Override language strings from template

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-programming/721-load-a-custom-language-file-in-your-joomla-template?_=1423205542726%27A=0), I tried to create a template specific language override, trying to be able to override *any* module or component. Basically, the idea is:

1. Create a file called `JOOMLA/templates/MYTEMPLATE/language/en-GB/en-GB.custom.ini`
2. Add this to the template `index.php` file:

   ```
   $language = JFactory::getLanguage();
   $language->load('custom' , dirname(__FILE__), $language->getTag(), true);
   ```

This works, and the language file is loaded, BUT it seems to be loaded before any extension-specific language file, making it impossible to override e.g. `mod_login`.

Is there any other way to do this, or some way to force the language file to be loaded last?

Answer (score 2):

You can create general Language Overrides in Joomla backend, **Extensions/Language Manager: Language Overrides**.

You can search for a string to be translated and define a new value. Even, if it is not found (but you know the label), then you can just create a new Override.

This tool is a simple way to create general language files in *language/overrides*.

TIP: You can even create overrides for default language labels. For example: language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini

```
COM_CONTACT_EMAIL_FORM="<i class="_QQ_"fa fa-envelope"_QQ_"></i>"
COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL="Email"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of that option, and it's very effective. But I was rather looking for a way to include a language override in my template, similar to layout overrides, so that when a user installs the template the string is overridden.

Comment: In opinion, you have to create a System Plugin to load the language file in a different moment. Most templates implement a System Plugin to have full control.